# Removing multiple keys from nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a large dictionary and I want to remove certain keys. I defined a set of unwanted keys, let's say it's called kunwanted. The dictionary looks like this:

```
   mydic= {'user':{'key1':'12','key2':'20','key3':30},
          'status':{'newk':'12','user':{'key1':'12','key2':'20','key3':30}}}
```

So, I have key 'user' as a key of mydic and as a key of mydic['status']. Let's say that in kunwanted I have 'key1' and 'key2'. Obviously, I can iterate 2 times through mydic to remove the elements:

```
for elem in kunwanted:
    if elem in mydic['status']['user']:
        del mydic['status']['user'][elem]

for elem in kunwanted:
    if elem in mydic['user']:
        del mydic['user'][elem]
```

is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a recursive approach:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import pprint

def recursive_remover(unwanted_keys, dictionary):
    for key, value in list(dictionary.items()):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            recursive_remover(unwanted_keys, value)

        if key in unwanted_keys:
            del dictionary[key]

def main():
    mydict={'user': {'key1':'12','key2':'20','key3':30},
           'status':{'newk':'12','user':{'key1':'12','key2':'20','key3':30}}}

    unwanted_keys = { 'key1', 'key2' }

    recursive_remover(unwanted_keys, mydict)

    pprint.pprint(mydict)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am getting it the right way, following might be helpful

```
for elem in kunwanted:
    if elem in mydic['user']:
        del mydic['user'][elem]
        break #
    if elem in mydic['status']['user']:
        del mydic['status']['user'][elem]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another recursive approach.

```
def recursive_remove(u_keys, d):
    # Remove keys in current dict
    for unwanted_key in u_keys:
        try:
            del d[unwanted_key]
        except (KeyError, TypeError):
            continue
    # Try to iterate over the items in dict, continue if not iterable
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        try:
            recursive_remove(u_keys, value)
        except AttributeError:
            continue


my_dict= {'user':{'key1':'12','key2':'20','key3':30},
          'status':{'newk':'12','user':{'key1':'12','key2':'20','key3':30}}}

u_keys = ['key1', 'key2']

recursive_remove(u_keys, my_dict)
```

Comment: @Blender Why? Although I agree that dstromberg's answer is cleaner and better, I don't agree that silently suppressing errors should be avoided as a general rule of thumb. On the contrary, silently suppressing errors can be very helpful in a lot of cases. Zen of Python: `Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.` KeyError occurs in the above code if the key isn't in the dict, TypeError occurs if the element is e.g. a string, AttributeError occurs when the element can't be iterated over.

Answer (score 0):

Condensing that into a single for loop should speed up execution slightly.

```
for elem in kunwanted:
    if elem in mydict['status']['user']:
        del mydic['status']['user'][elem]
    if elem in mydic['user']:
        del mydic['user'][elem]
```